# In which layer should the bootstrapper (container composer) should be present?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am building a WCF service. I am confused as where to place the bootstrapper which composes the container. I am using Ninject. The nuget package added a NinjectWebCommon class with composes the container on Start().

Should it be in Business Layer which all my command handlers?
Or should it be with the service?
Or there should be a separate layer (project) for the same?

I have looked up online but dint find any particular reason to put it with the service. 
Which of these is the best way to go and why?

Please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might already know, the `Bootstrap` represent the outermost layer of the complete architecture. This is where all your interfaces will be bound at runtime with the right implementation.

This is what is represented on that layer diagram:

[image]

Here's an example of how we deal with it from a `.sln` point of view.

[image]

As you can see, the `Bootstrap` is located in the `Presentation` layer. Even if it could be located in a separate folder, we decided to put it in there simply because the resulting `Bootstrap.dll` will be copied in the `/Bin` directory of the WebApp hosting your WCF services.

**Presentation/Bootstrap**: is the only project that reference your IOC (we're using `StructureMap` but it works exactly the same way with `nInject`). This is where you'll find things like:

```
private static void ConfigureCoreServices(this ConfigurationExpression c)
{
  c.For<IAccountService>().Use<AccountService>();
  ...
}
```

That's why this project must reference all the other ones (because implementations could be located anywhere). The `Bootstrap` project contains a `buildpost.bat` file as well. This `.bat` file will be executed as an `OnPostBuildEvent`. Its job will be to copy the `Bootstrap.dll` in the `/Bin` directory of the WebApp.

All the other projects in the `Presentation` layer are pretty straightforward.

**Presentation/Contracts**: Your WCF service contracts and DTO's
**Presentation/Implementation**: The classes that implemen your WCF service contracts
**Presentation/Mapping**: (If needed) Mapper class between DTO's and `Core` objects
**Presentation/WCF**: Only the `.svc` files

**Infrastructure**: This is where all our technology related classes are located (repositories implementations based on EF, logger classes, references to external/third parties services, things like that...)
**Core**: All business related stuff -> Domain model, interfaces, business services, ... With no reference to any kind of projects/libraries

Now, back to your root question, where's the magic?

We created a simple service behavior called `StructureMapServiceBehavior`, wich looks like this:

```
public class StructureMapServiceBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IServiceBehavior
{
  public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription desc, ServiceHostBase host)
  {

    foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase cdb in host.ChannelDispatchers)
    {
      var cd = cdb as ChannelDispatcher;
      if (cd != null)
      {
        foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
        {
          ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider =
          new StructureMapInstanceProvider(desc.ServiceType);
        }
      }
    }

    Bootstrapper.ConfigureBindings();

  }

  ...

}
```

The `Web.Config` file looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
          <StructureMapServiceBehavior />
          ...
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="StructureMapServiceBehavior" type="xxx.Presentation.Bootstrap.StructureMapServiceBehavior, xxx.Presentation.Bootstrap"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  ... 
</system.serviceModel>
```

You should have now enough information to get started!

Comment: The structure u gave is in context of Presentation Layer of a Web App. I am building an independent WCF service which will be consumed by applications in diff platforms (Web, mobile). So my bootstrapper will be on server side. Does this apply there too?

Comment: This is actually a Presentation Layer that hosts WCF services! Steps described here are only OK for WCF (behaviors, ...)